# Weird behaviour with strong tag within a height-defined element in HTML

Tags: html, css

Don't know if it has a normal explanation or if it is some kind of extrange behaviour, but i have faced the next issue in HTML:

I have the following paragraph:

```
<p>
    You have <strong>32</strong> items
</p>
```

Nothing so special and works fine. 
(Result: You have **32** items)

But if i add the following style:

```html
<p>
  You have <strong>32</strong> items
</p>
<p style="height:20%;">
  You have <strong>32</strong> items
</p>
```

The number in "strong" looses the spaces before and after it.
(Result: You have**32**items)

Why is it?

P.D: It behaves the same with "b" tag.

**More info:**

I'm testing in Chrome and Firefox with a IIS server (both fails).
I couldn't reproduce it in Fiddle, so it could be something that i'm missing in my code...

**More info:**

here is the complete scss:

```
$header_height: 10%;
$footer_height: 20%;
$body_height: 100% - ($header_height+$footer_height);

$container_frame_padding: 0.5em;


html{
    height:100%;

body.vcAllowOverflowContent{
    height:100% !important;

    .vcPopupContainer{
        height:100%;

        .vcPopupTitle{
            height:$header_height;
            display:flex;
            justify-content:center;
            font-size:$bigger_font_size;
            padding:$container_frame_padding;
        }
        .vcPopupBody{                
            height:$body_height;
            border: solid black 1px; 
            overflow:auto; 
            padding:$container_frame_padding;
        }
        .vcPopupFooter{
            height:$footer_height;
        }
    }
}
```

}

and here a more complete html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>MutipleDelete</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Bootstrap")
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/vcPopups.min.css" />
</head>
<body class="vcAllowOverflowContent">
    <div class="vcPopupContainer">
        <p class="vcPopupTitle">
            ¿Desea borrar estos <strong>@Model.Count</strong> pacientes?
        </p>
        <div class="vcPopupBody">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="vcPopupFooter">
            ...
        </div>

        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Bootstrap")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see i'm using Bootstrap and Razor.

If i remove the "vcPopupTitle" class, the paragraph behaves normally.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I don't have this problem.

Comment: updated the post...

Comment: It looks fine in the code snippet, which means its some own style of yours that might be overriding to get that behaviour

Comment: Check all styles that affect `<strong>` in web inspector.

Comment: It's strongly recommended (since HTML 5) that, if possible (even if not), use span class="foo" and then apply font-weight:bold; to this class, instead using html tags for text formatting.

Comment: I've updated the post with more info... sorry for not sharing it before but i didn't think it would be so complicated.

Comment: Mirate el post que acabo de poner abajo. Simplemente cambia strong por span y trabaja con lo que te he puesto, cada tag html tiene sus propiedades y si no las conoces es dificil trabajar con ellas. Lo mas importante es trabajar con las herramientas recomendadas y usar inspeccionar elemento desde chrome para ver qué CSS te está heredando o haciendo override a lo que tu quieres. Si es el caso avisame y te digo como solucionarlo. un saudo

Answer (score 1):

It's strongly recommended (since HTML 5) that, if possible (even if not), use span class="foo" and then apply font-weight:bold; to this class, instead using html tags for text formatting. 
And you cannot set width of text on %, must use px, em or rem, see the example below:

```css
p{font-size:1.2rem;}
p.ps{font-size:1.6rem;}
span.foo{font-weight:bold;}
div.container{height:86px; overflow:auto; border:0.1rem solid black;}
.section1{height:40%; border:0.3rem solid blue;}
.section2{height:60%; border:0.3rem solid red;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="section1">
  <p>
   You have <strong>32</strong> items
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="section2">
  <p class="ps">
  You have <span class="foo">32</span> items
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Take care about tag default properties and for which job are each one.
P tag is a paragraph and cannot take height property "as is". it will take 100% of the container on width, and the height it need. If you want to limit the height of a p tag, you have to limit the container of this p instead force limit to self P tag.

Note that if you try to force a container to a height and the content overflow its parent container, it will not take visible effect due to font-size (on this case) so you'll need to use another font size (and better specify it as rem, that means realtive em).

Comment: Upvoted becouse while it didn´t solved the problem, it focused me on the right direction.

Comment: Y gracias por el comentario en español ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved.

It has to be with the "display: flex;" and "justify-content:center;" styles.
I was applying those styles to a "p" tag, so the elements within it (text and strong) aligned to the center and spaces between them were removed.

Solution:

```
<div class="vcPopupTitle">
    <p>
        You have <strong>32</strong> items
    </p>
</div>
```

Now the "flex" display will work on the paragraph and not on its elements.